# Can Chronicle Queue become a Single Point of Failure?

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

Is Chronicle Queue resilient?

For example, if I had 50,000 clients all sending data to Chronicle Queue very frequently, how can I guarantee that all messages have been stored on safely in a distributed form?

What if Chronicle Queue goes down?

Would it then become a single point of failure in my messaging fabric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is Chronicle Queue resilient?

You can use chronicle-queue-enterprise ( a commercial product that extends the functionality of chronicle queue )  if you want to guarantee a copy to another machine.

> What if Chronicle Queue goes down?

Chronicle-Queue-Enterprise will guarantee all your events are replicated

> Would it then become a single point of failure in my messaging fabric?

If its replicated to another machine its no longer a single point of failure

If you are interested in chronicle queue enterprise please email sales@chronicle.software

Comment: Clear answers.  Thank you!